# Clear Fields Button (redirect not working)?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a webform with a "clear all fields" button, but it's not working properly. When I click the button on the rendered page, it directs me to another page on the local server, but not the one I have listed here.

```
protected void btn_Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/ContentRequest/PR_Event.aspx", true);
    }
```

I'm not sure what I can do...

Comment: You have to debug your code.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in this function to make sure it is getting hit as expected? Kinda hard withouth some more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `Request.RawUrl` to redirect back to current page.

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, true)
```

However, if you want to just clear fields, you might want to use jQuery or javascript at client-side to avoid a round trip to server.